# Sprint Planning Checklist in Jira

Tags: jira, agile, scrum, sprint

Recently my company took Jira for Agile project management. As part of our process definition, we have a list of items that need to be covered in Sprint Planning (we used to use a checklist in trello for managing them). In Jira, how do we incorporate the checklist in Sprint Planning?

Comment: Could you explain what kind of things are on your checklist? Are you talking about product backlog items? Or something else?

Comment: Example checklist items: Product Owner was Present, Only Done Items demoed, Backlog updated, etc.

Comment: You need to provide more details about it. Are you talking about Backlogs, Documentation Items, Project, Epic Tasks?

Answer (score 3):

To handle checklists in JIRA Issues you can have a look at this plugin [Checklist for JIRA](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.okapya.jira.checklist/server/overview).
For your use case I would prefer to handle Sprint Planning or any meetings in Confluence (if you can have it).
You can nicely link [Confluence](https://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) with JIRA Issues in both direction.

Comment: I'd suggest using a Confluence Meeting-Template as well.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options spring to mind.

You could create a custom issue type called 'Sprint Planning' and add to it custom field checkboxes for each item on your checklist.

Alternatively you could just add in an issue and put the checklist in the 'Summary' field.

There may also be checklist plugins for JIRA (although I don't have any personal experience of them).

Answer (score 0):

We also use Confluence page as a meeting agenda or checklist and the nice thing about Confluence page is that it is easy to reference issues from Jira and comes with a built-in checklist.